# Replacing older interior doors

Tags: doors, bedroom, interior

Recently bought an older house that's been well maintained. But, the four bedroom doors sag on their hinges and rub against the frame, making them hard to close. Most have gaps on the bottom of 1/2 inch to almost an inch, making it hard for a toddler to sleep with light and sound leaking through. Doorknobs are loose. At least the door frames still seem in good shape.

I'm trying some tricks to tighten up the hinges (tough, the hardware is all old) but it seems like any repair would be a partial fix at best so it might be better to replace them. Is this a job for a handyman, a carpenter, or a general contractor? Any idea how costly this would be? It seems hard to find and appraise different tradespeople in my area, so I'm trying to go into this with as much info as possible.

Comment: Older house might also mean good solid doors that will not find these days for decent(not an arm and leg) prices, compared to the cardboard filled doors of today.  Can you post pictures of the doors and the hinges?  Might only need longer screws, might just need simple repair.

Comment: I assume you mean to just replace the hinges, not the entire door. This would be a DIY or handyman job. I would recommend using longer screws as well. Note, if you have forced central HVAC, then you will need to retain those 1/2 inch gaps at the bottom unless you have alternate paths for your return air.

Comment: @ Glen Yates,  Make your comment an answer.  It's spot on.

Comment: If the rubbing is minor, it will likely go away with summer, but a plane or sander can erode the sticking point for little cost+effort.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the hinges is a DIY job.

Using new longer screws is recommended to get better grip.

Fill the old screw holes with  wood filler, then while it is still wet put a wet tooth pick in it to create pre-drill hole for screws then take it out and let it harden.

The gap at the bottom is sometimes used if you have forced air HVAC to allow for air flow unless you have air return in the room. It is not a must have so you can temporary close it.

Comment: Not sure that I'd count on wood filler to hold a screw, especially one used for a door hinge. My go-to fix has always been to coat several toothpicks with glue and stuff them in the screw holes. Once the glue dries, cut the toothpicks off flush (a utility knife will suffice, fancier saws are great, but not necessary), then just drive the screws back in. If you pre cut the toothpicks, you can even drive the screws while the glue is still wet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have 4 separate problems with the doors:

1. Sagging hinges. This is caused by the normal operation of the door over the years, when the screws come loose. You can try tightening the screws. If the screws are not biting into the wood, just replace them with longer screws (say 3" screws). This is a DIY job.
2. Old, loose hardware. This is easy to replace and also a DIY job. Just make sure that you get nice replacements that are similar to the old ones, to keep the charm of the old house.
3. Door rubbing against the frame. This might be fixed when you fix the hinges, but if not, just use a block plane to shave off some wood where the door is rubbing. Don't remove too much, as the door will shrink and expand with the seasons, and if you remove too much, you'll end up with a gap between the door and frame when it shrinks. If the door is rubbing against the frame, it's a DIY job, if it's rubbing against the floor, possibly a handyman as it requires to remove the door.
4. Replacing the door to remove gaps between the door and the floor. Old houses have solid wood doors, and these are really expensive and difficult to replace. Most doors you'll find at stores are pre-hung, which means that they include the frame. "Hanging a door" means installing a new door in a pre-existing frame, and it's a job for an experienced finish carpenter.